# How to customize shipping region/states on WooCommerce

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I added 3 States (they're regions, in fact) using [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-custom-shipping-regions/#post-12580213) snippet (in `functions.php` file):

```
/**
 * Adds States
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

  $states['UY'] = array(
    'UY1' => 'La Barra', 
    'UY2' => 'Punta del Este',
    'UY3' => 'Maldonado'
  );

  return $states;
}
```

And I added a couple of shipping methods for each new 'State'.

[image]

The problem is when selecting the shipping address on the checkout, it doesn't show the corresponding shipping methods available. E.g. 'Maldonado' It only shows the correct shipping methods if I enter 'UY3'

I tried changing UY3 for Maldonado too, like this:

```
$states['UY'] = array(
    'La Barra' => 'La Barra', 
    'Punta del Este' => 'Punta del Este',
    'Maldonado' => 'Maldonado'
```

but it doesn't work either. I assume that the 2 characters country code is required.

How can I make it work so the customers could insert the State name for the shipping methods to show?

**Notes**:

- WordPress 5.3.2
- WooCommerce 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Shipping -> Shipping options and change the Shipping destination options 
[image]

Comment: It was that easy!! Thank you very much!